# Javascript get result of Promise and return in a non async function

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

There is some library I use and it's function returns a promise.

```
function Something()
{
    return new Promise((r,e) =>
    {
        r(true);
    });
}
```

And I have my code:

```
//async function MyFunction() NO!
//function MyFunction(callback) NO!
function MyFunction() // -> BOOLEAN | void | undefined
{
    return Something();
    //return Something().then(/*actualy return*/).catch(/*return false or undefined*/);
    //Something().Wait().ReturnResult();
}

console.log(MyFunction());
```

How do I return boolean value? Without making my function a promise.

Comment: _"How do I return boolean value?"_... you cannot. Once you start working with asynchronous code, there's no way to make it synchronous. You'd need something like `MyFunction().then(console.log)` to log the value resolved by the promise

Comment: There must be a way to make a WAIT()

Comment: _"There must be a way to make a WAIT()"_ - `myFunction().then(result => { ... })` is a way to _wait_.

Comment: `async`/`await`

Comment: @ManTachi `put a async where not required` - yes, that would be dumb ... just don't use the library

Comment: @Yousaf that does not wait, that just redirects to another function

Comment: @Bravo I don't see any logic in all this promise,async,await if there is no possibility to WAIT. It makes no any sense, if it is a single thread what was the actual point of making this functionalities?

Comment: how is await not wait

Comment: It does not block and WAIT for the result. It creates another Promise since where you want to await MUST be ASYNC function. It is simply a callback loop.

Comment: @ManTachi Reading about [asynchronous javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) might help.